# Close and open dialog while new activity ended

Tags: android

I have activity with dialog. Then I go to new activity where I do some operation and back to main activity. And I want to show dialog with refreshed data. So I did

```
 @Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog.show();
}
```

because if I close it and re-open it manualy the data will change. If I check it in debugger dialog shows, but in normal runtime not. What can I do to close and open it?

Comment: you should try https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in onPause and onResume.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
dialog.show();
}
```

And in onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

**OR**

See [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: The first one does not work for me. About onActivityResult, it stoped work that's why I try to find new way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: call dialog.dismiss(); in onStop() and dialog.show(); in onResume() of your activity.

Solution 2: fire broadcast from your second activity and receive it to your first. base on it update data.

Solution 3: start activityForResult and on result receive, update your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the new activity like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then, to go back to the main activity passing the new data, you can use `.putExtra`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

//The object containing the updated data:
intent.putExtra("DATA", dataObject);

getActivity().setResult(200, intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

In the main activity, use `onActivityResult` to retrieve the data:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(data != null){
        if(resultCode == 200 && data.hasExtra("DATA")){
            DataClass dataObject = data.getParcelableExtra("DATA");
            //Here you can use the new data to update the content of your dialog...
        }  
    }  
}
```

Hope it helps...